# LINQ Join to delete contents from multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I have a question about LINQ delete. I have 2 tables in the database and they are joined.

First Table: `empid`, `empname`, `salary`, `dname`

Second Table: `dId`, `dname`

I want to delete one employee from the first table and all references from the child table also. I wrote the following code for that, tables remain in the same state after the query executed. How can I delete it by using LINQ? Please explain what changes are needed to get the right solutions.

```
public string DeleteData(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var emplist = new List<ViewDetails>();
        // tble_dept dept = new tble_dept();
        //tble_Emp emp = new tble_Emp();
        OperationDataDataContext dc = new OperationDataDataContext();
        var employess = from emps in dc.tble_Emps
                            join depts in dc.tble_depts
                            on emps.deptid equals depts.id
                            select new ViewDetails
                            {
                                empid = emps.EmpId,
                                empname = emps.EmpName,
                                salary = emps.EmpSalary,
                                dname = depts.Dname,
                            };
        var company = employess.FirstOrDefault(c => c.empid == id);
        emplist = employess.ToList();

        if (company == null)
            return "Company cannot be found";
        emplist.Remove(company);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
        return "ok";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the delete statement?

Comment: @markpsmith->emplist.Remove(company)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public string DeleteData(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var emplist = new List<ViewDetails>();
                // tble_dept dept = new tble_dept();
                //tble_Emp emp = new tble_Emp();
                OperationDataDataContext dc = new OperationDataDataContext();
                int q = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                var employess = from emps in dc.tble_Emps
                              join depts in dc.tble_depts
                              on emps.deptid equals depts.id
                              where q == emps.EmpId
                                select  emps;



               // if (company == null)
                  //  return "Company cannot be found";
                dc.tble_Emps.DeleteAllOnSubmit(employess);
               dc.SubmitChanges();
                return "ok";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DeleteAllOnSubmit`

```
var company = employess.FirstOrDefault(c => c.empid == id);
if (company == null)
   return "Company cannot be found";

dc.tble_Emps.DeleteAllOnSubmit(company);
dc.SubmitChanges();
return "ok";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Cascade on Delete** functionality is there in EntityFramework. If parent table is having one to many relationship with child table.  When parent table row is deleted the child rows get deleted or the foreign key column is set to null.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasOptional<Standard>(s => s.Standard)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

For more details about Cascade on Delete refer this link: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx